# To get all the (b,a,a+1) Pythagorean triplets

Tags: pythagorean-triples, pell-type-equations

In $(b,a,a+1)$
I found that $a+a+1=b^2$, in which $a>b$

You guys probably knew this but I randomly thought this thing in $5,12,13$ and then found it in all with $b,a,a+1$

So anyways
That means $2a+1=b^2$
If we take b as any odd number and the reason for odd is so that we can get $b^2$ as odd number and then $b^2-1$ be a even number and as $b^2-1=2a$, we will get a integer $a$

So, $b = 2n+1$
so for each value of $n$, we get a triplet and yeah it's cool to have all triplets of this form

Eg.

1. $n = 5$: $b = 11$
   $2a+1 = 121$
   $a = 60$
   So the triplet is $(11,60,61)$
2. $n = 8$: $b = 17$
   $2a+1 = 289$
   $a = 144$
   So the triplet is $(17,144,145)$

My question is I can't be anywhere near smart just by studying high school maths, and this isn't a hard find. So why this all was never taught to us yet.And sorry if this was very dumb...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a question. That said, good for you for figuring something out for yourself. You can find more on this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Comment: "So anyways That means $2a+1=b^2$."  Huh???

Comment: "So why this all was never taught to us yet?" You should ask your math teacher.

Comment: It's not a dumb question and you don't have to be sorry about anything. Isn't the point of asking questions on this site to gain some valuable insight and to learn stuff? Pythagorean triples are definitely famous in the math world, but good on you to find out about them yourself. 

Comment: You may also enjoy exploring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples

Comment: There are way too many things to teach. So you generally teach things that will be used later on in Math (in school anyway). At least in my curiculum, we never used Pythagorean triples, so while interesting, it would be pointless to teach them.

Comment: I think before an edit the title of the question (though not the body) was about Pythagorean triples of the form $(a,a+1,b)$; and that other question was a fairly interesting question to investigate.

Comment: @DanielSchepler that was my mistake, cause this was my first question. I wrote it wrong. but that was -a^2+(a+1)^2=b^2. You can try if you see something in this

Comment: Actually, it looks like the answer by poetasis already addresses that version of the question, and that answer's expression is very closely related to the answer I found independently.  (Though my formulation was arguably easier to encode into a Python script to list out all such triples.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Yes, his answer is what I wanted. Still you can tell your expression. Thank you for assistance!

Comment: FWIW, the ancient Babylonians knew about triples of the form $(b, a, a+1)$ with $2a+1=b^2$. They had table listing many such triples, but it's not clear if they had a proof that it's always true. OTOH, the notion of proof didn't really become prominent before the ancient Greek mathematicians, and even then it was strongly tied to geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I developed a formula in 2009 that generates sets of Pythagorean triples where $\,C-B=(2n-1)^2\,$ for each set. If you let $\,n=1,\,$ then you get the triples in $\,Set_1\,$ where $\,C-B=1^2.\quad$
Side-$A\,$ is always of the form $\,2x+1\,$ so it can be any odd number greater than $\,1\,$ and $\,Set_1\,$ includes all of these.$\quad$ Side-$B\,$ is always of the form $\,4x.\quad$
Side-$C\,$ is always of the form $\,4x+1.$
\begin{align*}
&A=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k\\ 
&B=\phantom{(2n-1)^2+{}} 2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\ 
&C=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k+2k^2
\end{align*}

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 &k=3 & k=4 & k=5\\ \hline
Set_1&3,4,5 &5,12,13&7,24,25&9,40,41&11,60,61\\ \hline
Set_2&15,8,17&21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65&39,80,89\\ \hline
Set_3&35,12,37&45,28,53&55,48,73&65,72,97&75,100,125\\ \hline
Set_{4}&63,16,65&77,36,85&91,60,109&105,88,137&119,120,169\\ \hline
Set_{5}&99,20,101&117,44,125&135,72,153&153,104,185&171,140,221\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

On the other hand, if you want all triples where
$\,B=A\pm 1,\,$ you should use Euclid's formula
$\quad A=m^2-k^2\quad B=2mk\quad C=m^2+k^2\quad $

and derive the parameters from Pell numbers where

$$ m_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\qquad
 k_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

For example

\begin{align*}
m_1&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{2} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{2}}{2\sqrt{2}}=2
& k_1= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^1 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^1}{2\sqrt{2}}=1\\ 
     & F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\
\\    
m_2&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{3} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{3}}{2\sqrt{2}}=5
&k_2= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^2 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^2}{2\sqrt{2}}=2\\ 
     & F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
\\
m_3&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{4} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{4}}{2\sqrt{2}}=12 
&k_3= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^3 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^3}{2\sqrt{2}}=5\\
     & F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\ 
\\
m_4&= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{5} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{5}}{2\sqrt{2}}=29
&k_4= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^4 - (1 - \sqrt{2})^4}{2\sqrt{2}}=12\\
     & F(29,12)=(697,696,985)
 \end{align*}

Comment: oh yes, ty that's what I wanted. Really thank you. I kind of only did the set1

Answer (score 4):

This is a very good find. It is known, but being able to discover things on your own is an achievement in itself.

Here's something more for you--spot the pattern:

$$3^2+4^2=5^2$$
$$5^2+12^2=13^2$$
$$7^2+24^2=25^2$$
$$9^2+40^2=41^2$$
$$11^2+60^2=61^2$$
$$13^2+84^2=85^2$$

$$\vdots$$

Comment: Tysm, i was worried that I asked very dumb thing after above comments. I was going to delete this as I saw I am wasting time of ppl who do things in silicon valley and stuff. But I still want to know like, if we want a triplet (171,..,..) my method works so fast. So isn't that a reasonable thing. And ty for reading;-;

Comment: Your question was not dumb--it was poorly typed and will probably be closed soon, but I answered because it reminded me of when I was younger and would look at these beautiful patterns. I'm happy to see you're finding some of the cool things math has to offer, even if this site may not be the best place (yet)

Comment: Oh ty, and what about like to find a triplet with (171,..,..) what's the way to find it else then how I said in that

Comment: $171^2=29241$. Half of that is $14620.5$. So $(171,14620,14621)$ is a triple.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did, so is that the classical ways ppl find these triplets? Oh so that means I found smtg which was so common. Ok sorry sir ty very much. Will remember u

Comment: I found the same thing in geometry class about 12 years ago. Many before us probably did the same. I ended up pursuing a career in mathematics and have taught for the last three years. Don't let that candle of curiosity burn out

Comment: @VIBHU Check out this post I made today about how to find many more of them: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807522/proving-exhaustion-of-primitive-pythagorean-triples